# Change order of stacks in a bar plot

Tags: ggplot2, geom-bar

I have tried many things, but nothing seems to work! I think, I have to change the stack order while using geom_bar? I want to change the stack in the following order: DIC - POC - DOC (from top to bottom); original order is: DIC - DOC - POC... see picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGwfO.jpg)

Hope you can help me.

```
df <- read.table(header=T, sep=" ", text="
ID Date Type Value
A-1 2017-08-31 DIC 26.870107
A-2 2017-08-31 DIC 54.216603
A-3 2017-08-31 DIC 18.487286
A-1 2017-08-31 DOC 51.897025
A-2 2017-08-31 DOC 33.599756
A-3 2017-08-31 DOC 78.904307
A-1 2017-08-31 POC 21.232867
A-2 2017-08-31 POC 12.183641
A-3 2017-08-31 POC 2.60840")

ggplot(dat,aes(y=Value,x=ID,fill=factor(Type)))+ 
    geom_bar(position='stack', stat='identity')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After revisiting my script, I could answer my own question :)

I've inserted a dummy column with specific numbers in the order I want:

```
dat$Type_dummy<-NA
dat$Type_dummy[dat$Type %in% "DOC"] <- 1
dat$Type_dummy[dat$Type %in% "POC"] <- 2
dat$Type_dummy[dat$Type %in% "DIC"] <- 3
```

In ggplot I used `fill=factor(Type_dummy)` to use the dummy column and labelled it via `scale_fill_manual`.
Hope this helps others!